# How to add a button only once in a List View xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using this code

```
x:Class="Fit_Plans.TimelinePage"
Title="Timeline"
BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource MainWrapperBackgroundColor }  
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{ Binding TimelineList }" 
        SeparatorVisibility="None"
        BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource BasePageColor }"
        HasUnevenRows="true">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Grid x:Name="GridTasks">
                                    <local:TimelineItemTemplate  
                                    Padding="{ DynamicResource MainWrapperPadding }"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <artina:Button   
                            Clicked="OnNextButtonTapped" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource PrimaryActionButtonStyle}" 
                            Text="Order" 
                            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            WidthRequest="{ artina:OnOrientationDouble
                            LandscapeTablet=600 }"
                            HorizontalOptions="{ artina:OnOrientationLayoutOptions
                            PortraitPhone=Fill,
                            LandscapePhone=Fill,
                             PortraitTablet=Fill,
                            LandscapeTablet=Center }"/>

                            <StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Result :**

[image]

But if I want to display the order Button only 1 time at the end of the list view , how to achieve that?

I have tried this with no success :

```
<ContentPage.Content>


    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{ Binding TimelineList }" 
        SeparatorVisibility="None"
        BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource BasePageColor }"
        HasUnevenRows="true">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                   <ViewCell.View>
                       <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Grid x:Name="GridTasks">
                                    <local:TimelineItemTemplate  
                                    Padding="{ DynamicResource MainWrapperPadding }"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout>
                           </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
<artina:Button   
    Clicked="OnNextButtonTapped" 
    Style="{DynamicResource PrimaryActionButtonStyle}" 
    Text="Order" 
    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
    WidthRequest="{ artina:OnOrientationDouble
                            LandscapeTablet=600 }"
    HorizontalOptions="{ artina:OnOrientationLayoutOptions
                            PortraitPhone=Fill,
                            LandscapePhone=Fill,
                             PortraitTablet=Fill,
                            LandscapeTablet=Center }"/>
```

It displayed the button at the end but with an empty list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListView provides `HeaderTemplate` and `FooterTemplate`. You should put your button inside `FooterTemplate` as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{ Binding TimelineList }" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource BasePageColor }" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                      .................
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
              //Put your button here
            </ContentView>  
         </DataTemplate>  
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Using  `<ListView.Footer> </ListView.Footer>` solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

As of previous answer you can put in in footer or if you'd want to keep he button inside the cell template then wrap the button in with a IsVisible = your custom converter, that would check `if (myIndex == totalListCount)` then the button would be displayed for the last item in list only.

Comment: Nick, However, this may solve the purpose but its not a good approach to accomplish this. This creates one instance of button per ListView item.